# How to export consistent subset of database

Tags: database, dump, subset

I'm certain that there must already be a many tools "out there" to do this, but I'm not having much luck tracking them down. I'd greatly appreciate your help.

We have pretty big MySQL database, with many tables and some complex table relationships enforced via foreign key constraints. What we need is, to create another, smaller database with subset of data and tables.

For example, I have a time schedule of courses and I want to create database revision with only 2 courses and enlisted students. Basically, what we want i to enter "root condition" and tables we want and the tool should create consistent dump or database with all needed tables.

I spend some time searching the internet, but i found only [Datamaker](http://www.grid-tools.com/datamaker.html), which is proprietary and doesn't even have trial download, and Jailer, which looks fine, but I founded it little bit difficult to use...

I would very appreciate tips for some other tools which can do this.

I'm not sure if I've explained this very well - please let me know if I didn't :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try Jailer http://jailer.sourceforge.net/exporting-data.htm

Answer (score 0):

assuming "create consistent dump or database" is manual, you can simply write some views with the condition you want, export the view and upload to your other database. (cron the process if you want)

if you want make it fully automatic, then it's a lot more complex, setup a slave mysql server will be recommended to ensure consistency, but it will basically copy the whole db.

hope that helps.